# Line ChartJs would not display - Date format issue

Tags: html, django, date, django-templates, chart.js

I am trying to plot a line chart using Django and ChartJs.

I created a list of dates in my view file that I would like to use as x-axis data in my chart.
I rendered my list of dates in my template through built-in template tags {{ date }}. When I inspect the HTML file and see the content of my labels, the list has &#x27 prior each date element in my list (see capture).

[HTML inspection capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gokht.png)

I think this is why the chart would not display but I can’t figure out why I have this added in my list. Do you guys have any idea ?

Thank you for your help.

```
[from django.shortcuts import render
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

def HomeView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = yf.download(tickers='SAF.PA')
    data\['Date'\] = data.index
    data\['Date'\] = data\['Date'\].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    context = {
        "Date"  : data.Date\[0:5\].tolist(),
        "Close" : data.Close\[0:5\].tolist()
    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to resolve my list issue. Here is the code:

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [{% for Date in Date %}"{{ Date }}",{%endfor%}],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'SAFRAN',
            data: {{ Close }},
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        }]
    },
});
</script>
```